# Dots in field aren't used to break up word for analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following mapping for the index documents (simplified)

```
{
    "documents": {
        "mappings": {
            "document": {
                "properties": {
                    "filename": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "lower_case_sort": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put two documents to this index

```
{
    "_index": "documents",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "777",
    "_source": {
        "filename": "text.txt",
    }
}
```

...

```
{
    "_index": "documents",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "888",
    "_source": {
        "filename": "text 123.txt",
    }
}
```

Doing a query_string or simple_query_string query against "text" I would have expected to get both documents back. They should match due to the filenames are "text.txt" and "text 123.txt".

```
http://localhost:9200/defiant/_search?q=text
```

However, I only find the document with the name "test 123.txt" - "test.txt" is only found if I search for "test.*" or "test.txt" or "test.???" - I MUST add the dot in the filename.

This is my explain result against document id 777 (text.txt)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/document/777/_explain' -d '{"query": {"query_string" : {"query" : "text"}}}'
```

-->

```
{
    "_index": "documents",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "777",
    "matched": false,
    "explanation": {
        "value": 0.0,
        "description": "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
        "details": [{
            "value": 0.0,
            "description": "no match on required clause (_all:text)",
            "details": [{
                "value": 0.0,
                "description": "no matching term",
                "details": []
            }]
        }, {
            "value": 0.0,
            "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
            "details": [{
                "value": 0.0,
                "description": "# clause",
                "details": []
            }, {
                "value": 0.47650534,
                "description": "_type:document, product of:",
                "details": [{
                    "value": 1.0,
                    "description": "boost",
                    "details": []
                }, {
                    "value": 0.47650534,
                    "description": "queryNorm",
                    "details": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Did I screw up the mapping? I would have thought that the '.' is analyzed as a term separator when the document is indexed...

Edited: Settings of case_insensitive_sort

```
{
    "documents": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1473169458336",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "case_insensitive_sort": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide the settings(tokenizers, filters) of `case_insensitive_sort`?

Comment: Updated the original question. Not sure if this is relevant, as the default analyzer should apply to the query. "case_insensitive_sort" is only used in a subfield of filename. Resp. filename.lower_case_sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be expected behavior of `standard analyzer`(Default analyzer) since it uses [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) and as per the [algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries) used by it, **dot** is not considered as separating character.

You can verify this with the help of [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "test.txt"
}'
```

only single token is generated

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test.txt",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

You could use [pattern replace char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) to replace dot with empty space.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "replace_dot"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "replace_dot": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\.",
          "replacement": " "
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would have to **reindex** your documents and then you will get desired results. *Analyze api* is very handy to check how your documents are getting stored in inverted index.

**UPDATE**

You would have to specify the name of field you want to search on. The following request looks for *text* in [_all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) which by default uses standard analyzer.

```
http://localhost:9200/defiant/_search?q=text
```

I think following query should give you desired result.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?q=filename:text'
```

Comment: The analyzer works. I added the custom analyzer but re-indexing didn't help.

Comment: I created a new index and still no luck there... I defined the mapping with "filename": {"type":"string", "analyzer":"my_analyzer"} - but to no avail. If I call localhost:9200/_analyze on the new index against the new analyzer, the string is broken up perfectly. I think, I'm still missing something.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if this does not work

Comment: thanks for taking your time! I got all sorted out. I added the new analyzer in the analysis.analyzers.default and added a lowercase filter. This applies now as a search and index analyzer and everything is behaving as it should.

Comment: @m_c i am in the same boat, and can't figure out this part, "I added the new analyzer in the analysis.analyzers.default and added a lowercase filter"