# How to make Elasticsearch match documents containing full stop as word separator

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

i have documents in `elasticsearch` which contains `.` i.e. `full stop` as a word separator in the title.

e.g `title`

```
The.Handmaids.Tale.S02E05.WEBRip.x264-TBS[ettv]
```

so if i search for `"The Handmaids Tale S02E05 WEBRip"`

my `elasticsearch` query becomes

```
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['title'] = The
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['title'] = Handmaids
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['title'] = Tale
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['title'] = S02E05
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['title'] = WEBRip
```

And this query doesnt returns the above document.

So how can i make `elasticsearch` ignore . aka full stop in the title and return that document when i am searching for "The Handmaids Tale S02E05 WEBRip" ?

I am using latest `Elasticsearch 6.3`

my current `index mapping` is

```
"mappings": {
    "content": { 
        "properties": { 
            "title":{ 
                "type":     "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": { 
                        "type":  "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "tags":         { "type": "text" },
            "category":     { "type": "short" },
            "sub_category": { "type": "short" },
            "size":         { "type": "long" },
            "uploaders":      { "type": "integer" },
            "downloaders":      { "type": "integer" },
            "upload_date":  {
                "type":   "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "uploader":{
                        "type":     "text",
                        "fields":   {
                                    "raw": { 
                                        "type":  "keyword"
                                    }
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

update1 : from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136928/1642018

i came up with this

```
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "my_analyzer": {
      "type":      "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "char_filter": [
        "replace_dot"
      ]
    }
  },
  "char_filter": {
    "replace_dot": {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "\\.",
      "replacement": " "
    }
  }
}
},
```

and in mappings like this

```
"title":{ 
    "type":     "text",
     "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
    "fields": {
        "raw": { 
            "type":  "keyword"
        }
    }
},
```

I created a new index and still no luck there
I defined the mapping with `"title": {"type":"string", "analyzer":"my_analyzer"}` - but to no avail.

If I call `localhost:9200/_analyze` on the new index against the new analyzer, the string is broken up perfectly.

e.g.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/newindex3/_analyze?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "John.Doe.mill.dane"
}
'
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "John",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "Doe",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "mill",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "dane",
      "start_offset" : 14,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

But search is still not returning the expected document.

what am i missing ?

---

update2: for now, i am santizing title, just before inserting in index, by using

```
'title' => str_replace('.', ' ', $results[$i]['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand how analyzers work in elasticsearch.

Since you have not mentioned any analyzer in your mapping on **field title** , standard analyzer will be used.

Now you need to see how standard analyzer will produce tokens based on your text , that is how it stores tokens for searching

Here is an example of you text

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["The.Handmaids.Tale.S02E05.WEBRip.x264-TBS[ettv]"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

And below is the result

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "the.handmaids.tale.s02e05",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "webrip.x264",
      "start_offset": 26,
      "end_offset": 37,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "tbs",
      "start_offset": 38,
      "end_offset": 41,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "ettv",
      "start_offset": 42,
      "end_offset": 46,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the reason why your query is not working as it works on exact match of tokens.

What you need to do is make a custom analyzer like below

```
PUT test_pattern
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type":      "pattern",
          "pattern":   "\\."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And change analyzer in your mapping to **my_analyzer**

```
"mappings": {
    "content": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "category": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "sub_category": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "size": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "uploaders": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "downloaders": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "upload_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "uploader": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i created new index as per your suggestion and inserted 2 documents, "John.Doe.mill.dane" and "John Doe mill dane" and when i search for "john" i am only getting one "John.Doe.mill.dane", why am i not getting other ? Thanks

Comment: Because you created a rule that the text will only be seperated based on ",".You need to add all the rules in regex.Try understanding what are tokens, how searching occurs in elasticsearch .Don't just randomly use it